# xslt retrieve information from <a>

Tags: html, xslt

```
<div>    
   <a href="M_TestNamespace_StoredNumber_Swap``1_2_890a5ef1.htm">
         Swap
         <span class="languageSpecificText">
            <span class="cs">&lt;</span>
            <span class="vb">(Of </span><span class="cpp">&lt;</span>
            <span class="fs">&lt;'</span><span class="nu">(</span>
         </span>
         T
         <span class="languageSpecificText">
            <span class="cs">&gt;</span>
            <span class="vb">)</span>
            <span class="cpp">&gt;</span>
            <span class="fs">&gt;</span>
            <span class="nu">)</span>
         </span>
    </a>
<div>
```

I would like using XSLT and translate above into the result like this:

```
<div>
   Swap(T)
<div>
```

FYI, the "(" and ")" are from `<span class="nu"/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to create a parameter to hold the 'nu' value.

```
<xsl:param name="lang" select="'nu'" />
```

Then, you would be able to extract the language specific text like so

```
<xsl:template match="span[@class='languageSpecificText']">
   <xsl:value-of select="span[@class=$lang]" />
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html"/>

   <xsl:param name="lang" select="'nu'" />

   <xsl:template match="a">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="span[@class='languageSpecificText']">
      <xsl:value-of select="span[@class=$lang]" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a/text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<div>Swap(T)</div>
```

Change the parameter to 'vb' and you get the following

```
<div>Swap(Of T)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="div">
        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(a/text()[1])"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="(.//span/span[@class='nu'])[1]/text()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(a/text()[2])"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="(.//span/span[@class='nu'])[2]/text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've assumed that the `<div>` is correctly closed :).

Answer (score 0):

**One of the shortest ways to generate the wanted result is:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="a">
  <div><xsl:apply-templates/></div>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="a/text() | span[@class='nu']/text()">
     <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**:

1. All text nodes are ignored by: `<xsl:template match="text()"/>` -- this effectively "deletes" them from the output.
2. Only the text-node children of `a` and `span[@class='nu']` are treated differently (used to generate text-nodes in the output -- by the template matching: `a/text() | span[@class='nu']/text()`.
3. The unwanted white-space in the text-node children of `a` is removed using the standard XPath function **[`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space)**